# NDSolve misses nontrivial solution

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

The initial value problem I would like to solve possesses an analytical solution

```
U = Values@DSolve [{u'[t] == 1 - (1 - Sqrt[u[t]])^2, u[0] == 0}, u, t][[1, 1]];
(*Function[{t}, 4 E^-t (-1 + E^(t/2))^2]*)

Plot[U[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

If I try to solve the problem using `NDSolve`

```
NDSolve[{u'[t] == 1 - (1 - Sqrt[u[t]])^2, u[0] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Mathematica evaluates only the solution `u[t]==0`. Not surprising because the initial conditions describe equilibrium.

How can I force Mathematica to evaluate the nontrivial solution **numerically?**

Thanks!

Comment: Differentiate the ODE and find ICs that capture your desired solution? (Might need to differentiate twice, so that `u''[0]` can be an IC.)  Alternatively, rationalize first.  If I get time, I'll test unless you or someone else solves it first.

Comment: You can try `NDSolve[{u'[t] == 1 - (1 - Sqrt[u[t]])^2, u[0] == $MachineEpsilon}, u, {t, 0, 10}]`

Comment: @Nasser Thanks! It works, how easy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `ode2` below, we have to use the given ode after differentiating it to remove the singularity at `u[t] == 0`:

```
ode1 = u'[t] == 1 - (1 - Sqrt[u[t]])^2;
ic0 = u[0] == 0;

ode2 = Simplify[
   D[ode1 /. Equal -> Subtract, t] /.
    First@Solve[ode1, u'[t]]
   ] == 0
ic1 = First@Solve[{ode1 /. t -> 0, ic0}] /. Rule -> Equal
(*
  -2 + 3 Sqrt[u[t]] - u[t] + u''[t] == 0
  {u[0] == 0, Derivative[1][u][0] == 0}
*)

uFN = DSolveValue[{ode1, ic0}, u, t];
sol = NDSolve[{ode2, ic1}, u, {t, 0, 10}];

Plot[{u[t], uFN[t]} /. sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness /@ {6, 3}, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

---

Here's a cute way to kick the solution off the (unstable) singular solution, which I don't recall seeing on this site:  Subtract a perturbing function `q[t]` from the solution, let `NDSolve` integrate the `q[t]` plus difference to yield the desired solution. It's remarkably robust to the choice of `q[t]`.  Since it is possible to deduce `u''[0] == 2`, I would choose a function asymptotic to `t^2` near `t == 0` and one that vanishes as `t` increases.

```
q[t_] = t^2/(1 + t^4);
vode = {ode1, ic0} /. u -> Function[t, q[t] + v[t]] // ExpandAll // Simplify
sol = First@
  NDSolve[{vode, u'[t] == q'[t] + v'[t], ic0}, u, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: The solution produced by `NDSolve[{ode1, u[$MachineEpsilon] == $MachineEpsilon^2}, u, {t, 0, 10}, AccuracyGoal -> 100, WorkingPrecision -> 40]` has `u[0] == 0`, but there's a certain amount of brute force being used, imo.

Comment: Thank you for this, as usual ,  clever answer . It worried me, that `NDSolve`-solution 
 depends on small perturbation `$MachineEpsilon` !